# Synchronazing data between all MPI tasks

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, synchronization, mpi

Let's say that we split a problem of finding maximum value into n parts and each of n tasks has a variable *localmax* which is used to find some kind of maximum value. The closer *localmax* is to the actual maximum value the faster program finds the original maximum value, so there is benefit in keeping *localmax* equal to the largest *localmax* value across all tasks. What are some feasible ways to accomplish this? 
This is an example pseudocode of the algorithm

```
while(!isWorkFinished()){
  possibleMax = lookForMax(localmax);
  if(possibleMax > localmax){
    localmax = possibleMax;
  }
}
```

Obviously sending and receiving *localmax* after each iteration would be a bad idea because most time would be wasted on communication, not calculation. I could do this synchronization every k iterations but how could this synchronization be implemented? A perfect scenario would be if any task at any time could receive a current largest *globalMax*, if it's lesser than *localMax* then send *localMax* to update *globalMax* in the master task. In code:

```
MPI_Recv(&globalMax, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
if(localMax > globalMax){
    MPI_Send(&localMax, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

But I can't think of a way to make it work. Perhaps it's because I am very new to MPI.

Another idea is to use master task to send all values of *localMax* and then broadcast the largest one? I guess reduce function could be used in that case but is it a good idea? If possible, I would like to not use barrier operations(no waiting until every task does something), because I predict that it will really slow down everything.

Comment: I think there isn't an ideal one-size-fits-all solution.  Your problem is very similar to designing a distributed branch-and-bound algorithm: googling this led me to https://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~yannis/publications/distributed%20abb.pdf (35 pages) and http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.124.1701&rep=rep1&type=pdf (47 pages), among others.

Comment: Yes, it's actually a branch-and-bound algorithm. I'll take a look at these documents, thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  If you come across anything useful in them, I'd encourage you to write an answer to your own question summarising it!

Answer (score 0):

Non-blocking communication could be your friend!

Use a root rank.

From here on assume:

1. When I say all ranks, I really mean all ranks except the root
2. I'm referring to all non-blocking communication.

Post receives on the root rank from all ranks, and on all ranks from the root rank.

Ping the receives on every N iterations on all ranks. If a value was received from root rank, compare and replace with your local max if it is bigger.

Every time a rank finds a larger number than that stored, have it send its new max to the root rank.

Have the root rank cycle through all its receive posts. If it receives a value, have it compared against the roots max value it has seen. If the value is larger than it has received, replace it and send it out to all ranks.

There won't be any synchronization which is good. The actual max in all ranks may be slightly lagged, but it isn't important to be 100% accurate.

Sounds like a fun parallel problem. Good luck!